# github page no carga o no encuentra la ruta de imagen

Tags: html, css, github

Github page no carga la imagen de la carpeta , Soy nueva en lo de paginas web seguí un  tutorial y todo ok. El problema es que no carga la imagen de fondo :

https://erikavaldez.github.io/Amuka-Estetica

probé con cambiar jpg a .JPG  , con cambiar la imagen a formato png también, y poner la imagen en el main sin carpeta.
Estuve varias horas no se cual será el problema este es mi codigo:
https://github.com/ErikaValdez/Amuka-Estetica

Espero que me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo debe ir en la pregunta... estas segura que estas buscando en la ruta correcta no?

Comment: Tu carpeta de imágenes esta al mismo nivel que el index.html, entonces tu sintaxis debería ser: `background-image: url('imagenes/maquillaje.jpg');`

Comment: – gbianchi♦  Muchas gracias por tus consejos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu carpeta de imágenes esta al mismo nivel que el `index.html`, entonces tu sintaxis debería ser:

```
background-image: url('imagenes/maquillaje.jpg');
```

Definitivamente era eso, solo que puse también JPG y ruteó la imagen, Muchas gracias!!!
Estuve muchas horas buscando la solucion  :')