# No me cargan las imagenes en GitHub Pages

Tags: github, aplicación-web, github-pages, repositorio

esta es la imagen, claramente es un problema en la ruta que no puedo encontrar, ni siquiera me cargan los archivos js..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado reemplazando el ../ por ./ y nada, tambien poniendo PNG a las imagenes en lugar de png. soy muy nuevo en esto, no puedo encontrar el error, muchas gracias.

Este es el repositorio:
https://github.com/CristianAlejandro12/website

Este es el Sitio:
https://cristianalejandro12.github.io/website/

Comment: Cristian revisa ésta info https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431913/github-page-no-carga-o-no-encuentra-la-ruta-de-imagen

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código (en texto, no imagen) que has utilizado.

Comment: Tienes muchos problemas. No lees, porque si hubieses leído mi comentario, sabrías que la edición que hiciste de poner imágenes  con código no es bien vista. Tus imágenes tienen la ruta `https://cristianalejandro12.github.io/website/chatgpt%20pag/html.png`. La ruta esta mal definida y evidencia el uso de ChatGPT cosa que deberías evitar, además a modo de comentario, tu CV dice que sabes de diseño y programación web. [edit] tu pregunta y déjanos ver tu código para ayudarte.

Comment: gracias amigo, intentare arreglar todo me di cuenta que tengo muchas cosas extrañas en el codigo, acabo de leer su comentario muchas gracias!

Comment: Tus imágenes están en el root del sitio así que la ruta debería ser mas corta. Algo como [https://cristianalejandro12.github.io/website/html.png](https://cristianalejandro12.github.io/website/html.png) y listo. Además supongo que en tu ambiente de pruebas tuviste que haber visto el mismo error o no?? Cualquier cosa acá estamos.

Comment: hola, en el ambiente de pruebas esta todo excelente. me cargan todas las imagenes y los scripts de javascript, pero aqui en github pages ni las imagenes ni los js cargan, vere que tal porque aun no encuentro solucion

Comment: Porque todas las imágenes tienen eso de ChatGPT en las rutas. Se puede ver en tu archivo **index.html**